# Constructor owner = msg.sender problem

Tags: solidity, remix

I set a constructor in Solidity (currently 0.8.7)
The code is in following

```
address payable owner;

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}
```

But when i tried to compile the code, the

> Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.
> --> FunctionExample.sol:9:5:
> |
> 9 | constructor() public {
> | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

Could you please explain the error I have made? thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor should not have visibility attribute. So just remove the `public` keyword.

Furthermore, you have marked your `owner` variable to be `payable`. Therefore you have to be sure that the `msg.sender` is of `payable` type. You can just cast it with `payable(msg.sender)` and get rid of the error, but that won't solve the issue that somehow you need to make sure that the sender can receive the native asset. Or just remove the `payable` keyword from the variable.